# Algorithms for keyphrase clustering

Tags: clustering, information-retrieval

Are there any standard algorithms for keyphrase clustering. There are several algorithms for keyphrase extraction from a corpus. For e.g. [this publication](http://aclweb.org/anthology/C/C10/C10-2042.pdf) reviews some of the popular keyphrase extraction algorithms. Example of possible keyphrases extracted from a corpus of real-estate data would be 'house prices', 'car parking', 'foreclosure', 'victorian houses', etc. A clever algorithm can cluster 'hardwood floors' and 'hdwd flrs' together. Another example would be clustering 'basketball court' and 'b-ball court' together.

Are there any algorithms to group semantically similar keyphrases together?

Comment: As for currently, this question is not about clustering. It is about text mining or semantic analysis and, maybe, implies topics such as stemmatization. Before you can cluster you must get the data in the unambiguous form.

Comment: @ttnphns: I agree, in fact my first problem was to cast this as a known problem. Is it synonym expansion? Near duplicates? Clustering?

I think I have made my requirement clearer with the examples. I believe some sort of contextual similarity based technique should help me here, that way I should be able to identify 'hardwood floors' and 'hwdw flrs' as near-duplicates, but I don't know of any such technique.